# Keep toggle button from one form ON when switching to a different form

Tags: c#, winforms, toggle

So basically, I have a C# winform and it has multiple pages (which are different forms) when going to one page to another it closes the previous form/page. However, I have a “Settings” page and on that form I have a toggle button. That toggle button changes the text of a label on form1. If I force the form the open while the “settings” form is open, the text changes. However, I do NOT want that form to actually open I just want the text to change but when I take out the form1.Show(); , and just toggle the button off and switch back to form1 the text is the original and when switching back to settings, the toggle button has re-enabled itself. I cannot figure this out.

Comment: How do you store/save that setting? Just setting a variable to a value in a form does not work, since it gets disposed when you close the form - depends on the [scope](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-of-variables-in-c-sharp/). More information is needed, please show your code or [create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)